# "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" error in RestAssured post request with body

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm using restassured library and at the below line i'm getting `"java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"` error caused by `"Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.lang.Class(java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.Class) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @36f6e879"` The baseURI is a http link and token_Body
is alphanumeric string. I"m not sure what exactly is the issue. My java -version yields

```
"java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)"
```

Code:

```
String bearerToken = given(). with().
              header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"). body(token_Body).
              when(). post(baseURI). then(). extract().asString();
```

Comment: try with java 11. It seems RA haven't supported java18 yet.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17: I am running on open jdk 11.0.13 and still getting same error, any help please.
.......
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue, and I have solved it by updating the dependency of restassured to 4.5.1